# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing ie_api:

Tags: python, dll, importerror, openvino, pyd

[image]

`from openvino.inference_engine import IECore()`

If `IECore()` is imported for inferrence through `openvino`, the above error occurs.

I tried various environment variables and various things, but it didn't work.
The imported environment is a virtual environment, but site-package was located in:

**C:/USERS/USER/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python38/site-packages/openvino.**

How can we solve this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problably need to call the setupvars.bat script to initialize OpenVINO. Depending on the OV version it can be found directly in the `openvino` directory or in `openvino/bin`.

Comment: Thanks !, I solved it in the following way

set PATH=C:/USERS/USER/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python38/site-packages/openvino/libs;%PATH%

and I know how to add it to environment variable.